# How can I preserve the React useState or useContext data when I refresh the page?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, session-storage

React newbie issues...

In react, when using useState or useContext, I have data showing up OK. However, if I refresh the page, then this data is lost and reverts to default data.

One example is if I use location.replace(gohere); to go to another page, then the useState or useContext current data is lost on the destination.

I am aware of 'sessionStorage' and can use that if needed.

Is there a way to set up useState and useContext so that the contents will be preserved if the page is refreshed?

Thanks

Comment: [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) or [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider using a hook that taps into either LocalStorage or SessionStorage. Both of these using cookies to persist data about a user. Session storage lasts as long as the tab stays open, and local storage lasts until the user clears it. Check out this link on [useLocalStorage](https://usehooks.com/useLocalStorage/) for an example using LocalStorage. With minimal changes this could also be modified for SessionStorage, if that's more the behavior you are looking for. (Note, it looks like this is a custom hook, so you'd need to add a file with this hook to your project and modify for your specific use case)